# Understanding view controller segues with MapKit annotations in Xcode and Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm having trouble understanding how to trigger a view controller when someone taps on an an MKAnnotation with MapKit.  I created a View Controller and a segue, gave it a custom ID and added this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var MapViewUI: MKMapView!

private func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotation) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowClientController", sender: nil);
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let aClient = Client(title: "Excavators", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0236, longitude: 37.9062), info:"A guy");
    MapViewUI.addAnnotation(aClient)

    super.viewDidLoad()
}}
```

And this is the Client class in case you were wondering:

```
class Client: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?;
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D;
var info: String;

init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String){
    self.title = title;
    self.coordinate = coordinate;
    self.info = info;
}
```

}

What am I not getting?  If anyone can shed some light on this I'd be very grateful. Thank you all.

Comment: Delete `private`. Make view controller the map view’s delegate.

Comment: Hi @matt , sorry to bother you, but when I add `mapView.delegate = self;` to my `viewDidLoad()` function, and remove `private` im getting this error.  

`Thread 1: "[<MyApp.ViewController 0x7fc994508550> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MapViewUI."`

And I'm certain that the Identifier for the view controller is correct. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Got it!  MapView was not connected to my source file from storyboard. Thanks again